# Where to put a json config file to read it?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to use an external json config file with the Xchange Lib. I have everything in `D:\EclipseWorkspace\myjavaproject\src\packageone\main.java` but I do not know where to put this `exchangeConfiguration.json`.

```
InputStream is = ExchangeUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bitcoinde/exchangeConfiguration.json");
```

Comment: **Here:** D:\EclipseWorkspace\myjavaproject\src\bitcoinde

Comment: doesnt work ... its in there : D:\EclipseWorkspace\myjavaproject\src\bitcoinde\exchangeConfiguration.json

Comment: That was what I wrote.

Comment: The result is null :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it has to be in D:\EclipseWorkspace\myjavaproject\bin\bitcoinde